# Can you get a sqlite3 database on AWS?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, sqlite, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I made a website that uses a sqlite3 database, and I'm trying to get my program on AWS using elastic beanstalk. I've been googling, but can't find any instructions/tutorials on how to get a sqlite3 database running on AWS. Does AWS support sqlite3? Is there some trick to making it work? And if not, what do you recommend? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to the documentation below which will help you to get to the Beanstalk console and add the SQLite3 to the AWS. This is for the MySQL but you can change the database engine to SQLite3 from Database settings.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html

Answer (score 2):

It would be **epic** if AWS released a service/ intermediate server for it. I love SQLite.

However, the problem is that SQLite ~ does not support transactions over NFS. I actually tried storing SQLite on AWS EFS and then mounting EFS from both AWS Lambda & Batch, so I hit this wall organically.

Given that cloud environments are largely multi-machine/node, you really start to see the benefit of a server-based approach like PostgreSQL.

Answer (score -1):

I am not entirely sure whether this is possible because I have not done it before, but I'll point you in the right direction.

There is documentation that shows you how to get started with a custom Amazon Machine Image (AMI) for your elastic beanstalk environment. So what I would recommend doing is:

1. install sqlite3 on an EC2 instance,
2. configure sqlite3 to your requirements,
3. ensure the instance starts the sqlite3 service on boot,
4. create an AMI of the instance,
5. follow this documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html

Please let me know how you go and I may be able to help if you get stuck along the way.

Comment: sqlite3 service?

Comment: I imagine if it was profitable enough there would be a sqlite3 service provided by AWS. If large enterprise businesses do not use it, AWS is not likely to provide it.

Comment: I was calling out in your answer in step 3 you said "ensure the instance starts the sqlite3 service on boot". I don't think such a thing exists?