# Can I use a DuckDB/SQLite on Amazon (AWS) for a Shiny app?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny

I would like to deploy my shiny app that uses a local DuckDB (similar to SQLite) but I can't quite figure out if I can just copy the whole thing to the Amazon AWS system and it work seamlessly. Anyone had an experience please?

This link suggest sqlite works but I need to use DuckDB:
[Can you get a sqlite3 database on AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60367843/can-you-get-a-sqlite3-database-on-aws)

Comment: It should be very simple as DuckDB installs as an R package. But it might depend how you will deploy it on AWS : EC2, EKS, ECS...

Comment: This was my understanding, but an IT guy who was trying to sell me hosting thought it might not work with their Microsoft azure. I'm looking at AWS EC2 but not familiar with EKS or ECS. Do you know of a resource that explains which I would need?

Comment: If you use ec2 you will install shiny server, otherwise use shiny server docker...

Comment: @HubertL Thank you very much. Would you add it as an answer and I will accept. Quick question: (but happy to open a new thread too). Do I need to do anything clever with the DB connections to allow multiple users to open an instance of the app at the same time? I've heard of the pool package which looks like it might help but I've not been able to get it run locally.

Comment: Sorry @HCAI, I don't know how to do that